# MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I am getting MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated error in the following code. This is a test code in which receiver process receives two messages from sender. In the first message it receives the value of the number of integers it receives in the second message. In the second message it receives those integers.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int rank,nodes;
    int i,j;
    MPI_Status stat;
    int size,wait;
    int msgs = atoi(argv[1]);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nodes);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Request req1;
    MPI_Request*** req = (MPI_Request***)malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request**)*msgs);
    for(i=0;i<msgs;i++){
        req[i] = (MPI_Request**)malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request*)*(nodes-1));
        for(j=0;j<nodes-1;j++){
            req[i][j] = (MPI_Request*)malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request)*2);
        }
    }
    if(rank==0){
        int sent=0;
        int data[10];
        int pendingThreshold=100;
        int sentThreshold=1000;
        int completed=0;
        size=2;
        time_t t;
        srand((unsigned) time(&t));
        for(i=0;i<msgs;i++){
            for(j=1;j<nodes;j++){
                size=rand()%9+1;
                printf("Sending size = %d at i=%d\n",size,i);
                MPI_Isend(&size,1,MPI_INT,
                            j,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&(req[i][j-1][0]));
                MPI_Isend (&data[0],size,
                                MPI_INT,j,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&(req[i][j-1][1]));  
                //Code for ensuring number of non blocking operations 
                //do not exceed a certain threshold
                if(sent==sentThreshold){
                    while(sent>pendingThreshold){
                        int k=0;
                        wait=1;
                        while(wait){
                            MPI_Test(&req[completed][k][0], &wait, &stat);
                            wait = 1-wait;
                            if(!wait){
                                MPI_Test(&req[completed][k][1], &wait, &stat);
                                wait = 1-wait;
                                if(!wait){
                                    k++;
                                    if(k==nodes-1){
                                        completed++;
                                        sent--;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        wait=1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }                           
                    }
                }
            }
            sent++;
        }
        //Code for ensuring all non blocking operations are complete
        wait = 1;
        printf("Finished\n");
        i=completed,j=0;
        while(wait){
            MPI_Test(&req[i][j][0], &wait, &stat);
            wait = 1-wait;
            if(!wait){
                MPI_Test(&req[i][j][1], &wait, &stat);
                wait = 1-wait;
                if(!wait){
                    j++;
                    if(j==nodes-1){
                        j=0;
                        i++;
                        wait=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        wait=1;
                    }
                    if(i==msgs){
                        wait=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Finished\n");
    }
    else{
        int data[10];
        MPI_Request req2;
        for(i=0;i<msgs;i++){
            MPI_Irecv (&size,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1);
            wait = 1;
            while(wait){
                MPI_Test(&req1, &wait, &stat);
                wait = 1-wait;
            }
            wait = 1;
            while(wait && i){
                MPI_Test(&req2, &wait, &stat);
                wait = 1-wait;
            }
            printf("Receiving size=%d at i=%d\n",size,i);
            MPI_Irecv (&data[0],size,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2);
            size=0;
        }
        printf("Finished rank=%d\n",rank);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

This program receives MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE after multiple successful send-receives. The error occurs when receiver process receives a wrong size of integers to be received in its second message. For example:-

```
Sending size = 8 at i=1496
Sending size = 2 at i=1497
Sending size = 7 at i=1498
Sending size = 5 at i=1499
Sending size = 5 at i=1500
Sending size = 5 at i=1501
Sending size = 4 at i=1502
Sending size = 9 at i=1503
Sending size = 4 at i=1504
Receiving size=8 at i=1496
Receiving size=2 at i=1497
Receiving size=7 at i=1498
Receiving size=6 at i=1499
Receiving size=6 at i=1500
Receiving size=6 at i=1501
Receiving size=6 at i=1502
Receiving size=6 at i=1503
```

The error occurs at message number 1499 and after that it is receiving the same size for the further messages received. I had run my code for 100000 messages to be sent to the receiver process.

The following code uses MPI_Iprobe and works fine even for 1000000 messages.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int rank,nodes;
    int i,j;
    MPI_Status stat;
    int size,wait;
    int msgs = atoi(argv[1]);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nodes);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Request req1;
    MPI_Request** req = (MPI_Request**)malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request*)*msgs);
    for(i=0;i<msgs;i++){
        req[i] = (MPI_Request*)malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request)*(nodes-1));
    }
    if(rank==0){
        int sent=0;
        int data[10];
        int pendingThreshold=1000;
        int sentThreshold=10000;
        int completed=0;
        size=2;
        time_t t;
        srand((unsigned) time(&t));
        for(i=0;i<msgs;i++){
            for(j=1;j<nodes;j++){
                size=rand()%9+1;
                printf("Sending size = %d at i=%d\n",size,i);
                MPI_Isend (&data[0],size,
                                MPI_INT,j,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&(req[i][j-1]));     
                if(sent==sentThreshold){
                    while(sent>pendingThreshold){
                        int k=0;
                        wait=1;
                        while(wait){
                            MPI_Test(&req[completed][k], &wait, &stat);
                            wait = 1-wait;
                            if(!wait){
                                k++;
                                if(k==nodes-1){
                                    completed++;
                                    sent--;
                                }
                                else{
                                    wait=1;
                                }
                            }
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            }
            sent++;
        }
        wait = 1;
        printf("Finished\n");
        i=completed,j=0;
        while(wait){
            MPI_Test(&req[i][j], &wait, &stat);
            wait = 1-wait;
            if(!wait){
                j++;
                if(j==nodes-1){
                    j=0;
                    i++;
                    wait=1;
                }
                else{
                    wait=1;
                }
                if(i==msgs){
                    wait=0;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Finished\n");
    }
    else{
        int data[10];
        MPI_Request req2;
        for(i=0;i<msgs;i++){
            wait = 1;
            while(wait){
                MPI_Iprobe(0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&wait,&stat);
                wait = 1-wait;
            }
            MPI_Get_count(&stat,MPI_INT,&size);
            printf("Receiving size=%d at i=%d\n",size,i);
            MPI_Irecv (&data[0],size,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2);
            size=0;
        }
        printf("Finished rank=%d\n",rank);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, why aren't you using `MPI_Wait` and `MPI_Waitsome` and instead are reimplementing everything with `MPI_Test`? Also note that `MPI_Irecv` immediately followed by a wait or test operation is **equivalent** to `MPI_Recv`. Why are you sending the count of elements explicitly? Just use `MPI_Probe` (or `MPI_Iprobe`) and then `MPI_Get_count` before you call `MPI_Recv`.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks. I have used MPI_Iprobe and now the code is working. Although I know MPI_Iprobe is the right way to do it but I still can't understand why receiver process receives wrong value of the size variable. I have used non-blocking communication to simulate the scenario in my project. In my project the processes are involved in other activities.

Comment: I don't know if that is the reason, but you are incrementing `sent` after each pair of sends while you are decrementing it by one after `nodes-1` pairs complete. Because of that, `sent` decrements `nodes-1` times slower than expected and since the breaking condition is based on the value of `sent`, `completed` reaches values where `reqs[completed][][]` are still uninitialised -> segfault. Also, you are not properly handling the case when `nodes-1` does not divide `sentThreshold`, in which case `sentThreshold % (nodes-1)` elements of `req[completed][]` will still be uninitialised -> segfault.

Comment: Otherwise, your code does not reliably reproduce the truncation condition with two processes on my system, even with 1000000 messages - it crashes in about 20% of the runs. Reducing `sentThreshold` to 500 eliminates the problem, which means that once again you are posting too many non-blocking operations at once.

Comment: @HristoIliev I hadn't considered these issues. Thanks. I have handled these by incrementing **sent** after send operation to all the other nodes is issued. I have also posted the code using **MPI_Iprobe** which is functioning for 10^6 messages with a **sentThreshold** of 10000. Therefore MPI is able to handle **10000*(nodes-1)** non-blocking operations issued at once and I don't think that it is a reason for the truncate error.